# Android:Onclick not finding onclick method

Tags: java, android, onclick

I am attempting to make a custom view that uses buttons, however, the `android:Onclick` for the two buttons cause the app to crash. The ClickListeners don't work either.

The error I am getting from running the debug tool is :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method addMenu(View) in the activity class com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'increase'
```

This is My java code :

```
public class MenuItems extends LinearLayout{

    private View plusButton;
    private View negateButton;
    private EditText priceBox;
    private TextView total;
    private TextView name;
    private int totalItems;
    private double totalPrice;
    private double price;

    public MenuItems(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MenuItems(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public void init()
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item,this);

        plusButton=findViewById(R.id.increase);
        negateButton=findViewById(R.id.decrease);
        total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ItemName);
        priceBox=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Price) ;

        total.setText("5");
        negateButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        plusButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                plusButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                increase();
            }
        });
        negateButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                decrease();
                negateButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        });

        price=0;
        totalItems=0;
        upDateTotal();
        String pString=priceBox.getText().toString();
        price=Double.parseDouble(pString);
    }
    public void increase(View view)
    {
        totalItems++;
        upDateTotal();
        System.out.println("plus");
        plusButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    }

    public void decrease(View v)
    {
        if(totalItems>0)
            totalItems--;
        upDateTotal();
        System.out.println("minus");
    }
```

This is all of my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/menu_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mohs.joey.seniorproject.MenuItems">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/ItemName"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="name" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/Price"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:hint="Price"
                android:shadowColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="0.00" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:text="-"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/decrease"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:onClick="increase"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="Amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/total"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

            <Button
                android:text="+"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/increase"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:onClick="increase" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I access MenuItems in this Method in a separate class :

```
public void addMenu(View view)
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);
        v.setId(menu);
        ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.backLayer);
        insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        menu++;
    }
```

This is my new main activity:

```
package com.mohs.joey.seniorproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ConcessionMenus extends AppCompatActivity {
    int menu=0;

    private View plusButton;
    private View negateButton;
    private EditText priceBox;
    private TextView total;
    private TextView name;
    private int totalItems;
    private double totalPrice;
    private double price;

    PopupWindow popup;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_concession_menus);
        plusButton=findViewById(R.id.increase);
        negateButton=findViewById(R.id.decrease);
        total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ItemName);
        priceBox=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Price) ;
//        TextView totalPrice=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalPrice);
    }

    public void addMenu(View view)
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View vw = vi.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);
        vw.setId(menu);
        ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.backLayer);
        insertPoint.addView(vw, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        menu++;
    }
    public Intent newIntent()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,Menu.class);
        return intent;
    }
    public void increase(View v)
    {
        totalItems++;
        upDateTotal();
        System.out.println("plus");
        plusButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    }

    public void decrease(View v)
    {
        if(totalItems>0)
            totalItems--;
        upDateTotal();
        System.out.println("minus");
    }

    public void upDateTotal()
    {
        total.setText(""+totalItems);
        totalPrice=price*totalItems;
    }

    public double totalPrice()
    {
        return totalPrice;
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where did you access the class MenuItem ?

Comment: I added the method from a separate class from which I access MenuItems

Comment: please show us some code

Comment: I added the rest of the xml code

Comment: how are calling the `addMenu()` method?

Comment: write @override over th onclick method!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the button want to perform the action when you click on it , it should be able to find the method `increase()` in your `MainActivity` class , since  the method `increase()` is on an other class , the button will never find the method and they will crash because you set the your layout xml to your main activity not for the class `MenuItem` , to fix that just move these to methods to your `MainActivity class`

OR

Pass a reference of your buttons to the class `MenuItems` and do what you want there

PS : the ids can be found by typing `R.id` , but you cannot work with these id since you set the content view to your `MainActivity`

Comment: I moved all the methods and other references to the main activity, but I am still getting exactly the same error

Comment: I added the new main activity